# Calling function inside function is not defined

Tags: jquery

First i have been searching for the solution but i couldn't find any.

I'm using this template below because of easy readability.
And trying to avoid nesting function inside function if possible.

But with it i cant figure out if is possible to call another function inside function when bound to event listener.

Edit:
Because of great help by user rand0m i finaly figure out how to make it work.

Below example with working solution

```
var users= (function($) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        init: function() {
            //Run this validation logic
            this.validation();
            
            // Cant call it here because it runs at document ready
            //this.ajaxcheck();

            //Will have multiple functions in here
            //  this.passwordResetValidation();
            //  this.loginValidation();
        },

        validation: function() {
         // This works when not in event listener function
         // Not the use case what i was looking for
         this.ajaxcheck(); 

              $('#form input').on('blur', function(){

                   ajaxcheck(); // Return ajaxcheck is not defined
                   this.ajaxcheck();// Return ajaxcheck is not a function

                    // Solution
           // When trying to call function need to invoke user object before
                    users.ajaxcheck();

            });
            
        },
        
    ajaxcheck: function() {
            console.log('ajax call');
        },

}

})( jQuery );

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    users.init();
});
```

Edit: made mistake in example

Comment: if `ajaxcheck()` is dertainly defined and in global scope, then it invoking the function would certainlyl call it.

Comment: I don't think the i understand what you ment with this.

Comment: I think you need to learn about scopes. Here's a decent tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

What I meant is, Because the function `ajaxcheck` is defined inside the return object, It is accessible inside the `validation function` by calling `this.ajaxcheck();` as they both are in the same level of scope. Here is a gist I've created with comments for you to understand: https://gist.github.com/ypk/303659beb2e74429858903052e0c2557

Comment: Yes you are right my understanding is not great, need to learn much more. The second method `this.ajaxcheck();` is not working im getting error this.ajaxcheck is not a function, but last method is working when not declared inside return.

Comment: I've added a comment explaining detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061857/1401808  Again in your example, the first time you are calling `this.ajaxCheck()` that is completely valid because it is in correct scope. But the second time, you are calling `this.ajaxCheck()` that is not valid, because the scope changed. How? Its because you have defined a function `$('#form input').on('blur', function(){ .... this.ajaxCheck() .... });` the second time, the `this` keyword will refer to `$('#form input')` and not `user`.

Comment: In order to access scope of functions/variables from outside a function, you need to pass in the scope or reassign the scope to temporary variable and then use the temporary variable as the scope. So in your case `   validation: function() {   var scope = this;  scope.ajaxcheck(); $('#form input').on('blur', function(){ scope.ajaxcheck(); }); }` should make the code work. What we have done here is, we have declared a variable called `scope` (you can call it anything) then assigned `this` to the variable; and then used `scope.methodName` to call it.

Comment: I know its all confusing at first, but if you learn about scopes, you will find it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an object `users` which when initialized, runs a function which in turn returns an object with methods as its properties.

The users object is globally available, i.e, you can use `users.something` anywhere as long as its initialized.

the functions that return from the user object have scopes limited to the return function where they're defined. They can only be accessible outside the scope using `user.functionName` in your case `user.init()` or `user.validation()` etc.,

but once you go a level inside the code to where the functions are defined, you are entering into the scope of the function which was used to create the `user` object. At this level, you do not have access to other functions as earlier, but only the methods or variables which are defined within the scope of the function you are in.

For example: I've added a function `consoleStatement()` below. and it will print out some console logs, if you run the code, you will observe that the console log for year will output different year the second time when you defined the year as `2019`.

```
var users = (function($) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    init: function() {
      this.validation();
    },
    validation: function() {
      $('#form input').on('blur', function(){

        // This will NOT work because there is no ajaxcheck defined here
        ajaxcheck();

        // This will work because the "this" keyword uses the object (this) 
        this.ajaxcheck();

        // This will definitely work because the function is available globally
        checkMyAjax();
      });
    },
    ajaxcheck: function() {
      console.log('ajax call');
    },
    consoleStatement: function() {
      var name = "Marco";
      var year = 2020;
      console.log('Name is: '+name);
      console.log('Year is: '+year);
    }, 
  }
})( jQuery );

function checkMyAjax () {
  console.log('ajax call again');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var year = 2019;
  users.init();
  console.log('Year is: '+year);
  users.consoleStatement();
});
```

Scope of a function lies with in the block it is defined, for example `function myFunction () {}` so in order to access variables and functions, they either must be in the scope of the function or must be available globally. I.e, outside all functions.

Here is a gist I've created with line numbers for you to understand clearly: https://gist.github.com/ypk/303659beb2e74429858903052e0c2557

Comment: This is great explanation, so i need to place object users before function and will work. `user.functionName`

Comment: You have changed your code in original post, which is a different from what you had earlier. I've left comments below the original post for its solution. And as for scopes, what you've mentioned is moving the function to global scope, which you could do, but best practises say that we should not add to global scope as it will pollute it. Here's another resource to read about scopes: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-variable-scope/